# python code to execute multiple queries and create csv

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am pretty new to python I have a code that reads mysql query thorugh pandas and if there is data converts it into the csv now I need to move a step ahead and add another query and create another csv I am not sure what will be the best way to do it. Any help is appreciated thanks.

My code is something like this

def data_to_df(connection):
query = """
select * from abs
"""
data = pd.read_sql(sql=query,con=connection)
return data
def main():

```
# DB connection and data retrieval
cnx = database_connection(db_credentials)
print(cnx)
exit()
df = data_to_df(cnx)
```

## Convert Dataframe to textfile

```
df.to_csv(file_location, sep = '|', na_rep = 'NULL', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print('File created successfully! \n')
```

how can I add another query that will be executed and will create a different file altogether

Comment: what do you want to query? and what do you want to put in this different file?

Comment: yep I want to use this script to run two different queries and create two different csv files

Comment: The pythonic way would probably be to have a function for your queries and one for the CSV saving and call those each time you need to make a new query... besides that, just write the second query and csv saving after the first one, no?